# iterative closest point library

Tags: algorithm, maps, depth

is there any c++/c open source implementation? i got two point clouds and would like to match them.. any ideas?

Comment: how exactly do you want to match them? Any diagram or example would help.

Comment: i have two point clouds (a fixed model shape and data shape) of an object! now i try to algin the data to the model and get the distances of each point... later on i am using this distances in a svm to classify the data shape.. what i need now is an efficient implementation of the ICP, maybe hierarchical? my point clouds  consist of 30.000 points...

Answer (score 1):

Give LibICP a shot, although I personally have not used it so far.

http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libicp.html

EDIT: I tried it by myself, not a great experience -- the library is short of documentation and example code. Also, I didn't receive much help from the authors too.

Comment: It's also worth noticing that if `libicp`'s SVD does not converge (the limit of 30 iterations is hard-coded), it will print something to stderr and continue - it has no API to tell your code about non-convergence.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a article about accelerated line search on ddj.com some time ago. I dont exactly understand what you want to do but the approach shown there divides the whole area into "quadrants" of a given search width. This reduces the time for search significantly. It may also be used with points.

http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/198900559

Answer (score 0):

You can compare these 2 clusters of points by measuring [Hausdorff distance](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/98/normand/main.html)

between clusters. The bigger Hausdorff distance is - the more dissimilar clusters are.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to trimesh2 library, which provides a ICP example.
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/gfx/proj/trimesh2/

Comment: its not for matching point clouds? it uses two meshes, right?