# Is an implementation of Iterative Closest Point (ICP) available in R?

Tags: r, curve

Does someone have an implementation of [Iterative Closest Point (ICP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) algorithm for two dimensions (2D) in R?

Here is an attempt in c#
[Iterative Closest Point Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423016/iterative-closest-point-implementation)
Here is a more general question
[iterative closest point library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554017/iterative-closest-point-library)

[This is to match two sets of points through translation and scaling.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826625/how-to-align-and-scale-two-curves-using-scaling-and-translation)

Comment: R bindings to PCL would do it, I guess: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php [C++ point cloud analysis library]

Comment: PCL seems to be a behemoth, when I only want ICP.  Also, PCL is focused on 3D.

Answer (score 4):

Spacedman's comment is probably best.  You might also take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/loadFile.do?objectId=12627&objectType=file for a matlab implementation. Assuming it works ok, translating Matlab to R code is relatively easy.

Comment: True!  I am still lazily hoping that someone out there has done the leg work to bring this into R.  There also a few comments of problems with the matlab code.

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat of an answer in the form of a non-answer.

There are many variants of ICP.  The design choices are at least partially organized by the late 90's Ph.D. work of Pulli and by Rusinkiewicz & Levoy.  If you're going to be using ICP for anything remotely important (translation: "more than just a class assignment"), you should understand the tradeoffs.

Thus, it's probably best to take one of the existing implementations and port it to R.

Answer (score 2):

3 Years too late, but there is the function icpmat in the package Morpho by the same person who wrote Rvcg. I don't know which variant is implemented though.

Link:
https://github.com/zarquon42b/Morpho

Comment: Thank you for updating for those of us who are finding this post many years later.

Answer (score 1):

There is a self-contained (as far as I can tell) C++ implementation of ICP [here](https://github.com/ziyan/default/tree/master/algorithms/icp). Maybe you can create your own R wrapper around this C++ code.